# Where can i find the jboss-j2ee.jar file in JBoss 6?

Tags: jboss, jar, jboss6.x

In jboss 4.0 the file called jboss-j2ee.jar. But i can't find this jar in jboss 6.0's client directory. I need just for compilation to resolve few annotation. I'm not using maven, so adding pom reference would not help. I have to download jar file from somewhere and it dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec.jar is enough for my purpose. Can be found in Jboss client folder

Answer (score 0):

Check [JBoss community wiki](http://community.jboss.org/message/554017) .

You can also [download the jars](http://www.findjar.com/class/activation/Locator.html)
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using JBoss EAP 6, I found this file suited my purposes:
**jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar**

Found here:
..\jboss-eap-6.3\modules\system\layers\base\javax\ejb\api\main